# Highlight and Disable highlighted days jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to disable and highlight disabled days on a calendar but nothing seems to be working using jquery and php mysql to retrieve disabled days from database.

Code:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arrDisabledDates = {};
    arrDisabledDates[new Date('02/22/2018')] = new Date('02/22/2018');
    arrDisabledDates[new Date('02/04/2018')] = new Date('02/04/2018');
    arrDisabledDates[new Date('02/16/2018')] = new Date('02/16/2018');
    arrDisabledDates[new Date('02/28/2018')] = new Date('02/28/2018');

    $('#datepicker').datepicker( {
        beforeShowDay: function (dt) {
            var bDisable = arrDisabledDates[dt];
            if (bDisable) return [false, '', ''];
            else return [true, '', ''];

        }
    })
    $('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {
        $('#my_hidden_input').val(
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
        );
    });

});

function highlightDays(arrDiabledDates) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
            return [true, 'highlight'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}

</script>
```

Comment: refresh datepicker after changes you done so far. $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("refresh");

Comment: @javed how exactly do you want me to do that